# How to use _redirect() method in Magento 2 model file

Tags: magento2, model, redirect-url, action

```
Magento\Framework\App\Action
```

Redirect method is defined in Magento controller interface

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
 */
protected $_redirect;
```

So i am aware about that if i **use controller Action** then it will work.

But i want use **specific model method to redirect the url**

File location

```
app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Model/TestManagement.php
```

and **function** goes like :

```
    public function Test(){
        $this->_redirect('rbvendor');
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code for the redirect from the model.

Add below code as the parameter in the __construct method of your Model

```
\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url, 
\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
```

Create object for both as below

```
$this->_url = $url;
$this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
```

Now, modify your function code.

```
public function Test()
{
   $CustomRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('rbvendor/index/index');
   $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($CustomRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
   exit();
}
```

Please let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: I recieved this error: - 
Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource in /var/www/html/wineconnection/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php

Comment: Hi @Ravi this is not working in my model file. It is showing this error "Please enter a correct entity model". Do you have any idea on this ? I am using Magento 2.3.4 CE